# How to find out if a tag is good to create or have?

Tags: discussion, faq

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.
>   Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be
>   able to answer by sorting questions into **specific, well-defined
>   categories**. [**Source**: [help/tagging](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)]

Almost every alternate day, I come across users who create a ton of new tags whenever they post a new question. It's necessary to remind ourselves that not all tags are useful in the long run. Getting rid of bad tags [is hard](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361) and the process often unnecessarily bumps old questions to the [front page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)!

I had [once mentioned](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/109/26):

> As a rule of thumb, avoid creating tags which, if used as a
>   stand-alone tag on a question, would probably make the question
>   unsuitable for this site.

and I believe that's still a useful rule of thumb. Especially so, for [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Anyway, I'd like to summarize some more important points about tags and tagging in [an answer](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/373/26) below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a **12-point test** for creating a new tag, say X. It is mostly an extension of the [**MAR Tag Test™**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2968)!

> 1. Does X have a universally unambiguous meaning?
> 2. Does there exist a published paper (in a reputable venue) which defines X? Does X have a corresponding Wikipedia page?
> 3. Does "experts on X" make sense?
> 4. Does "I'm studying X" make sense?
> 5. Would you leave and **not** retag a question with only X as its tag?
> 6. Will "because it's related to X" be the only reason a question is tagged with X?<sup>1</sup>
> 7. Will X **not** be misinterpreted, just judging by its name?
> 8. Are there many (>15) but **not** too many<sup>2</sup> questions on the site with the search keyword "X"?
> 9. Will people search using "X" to find questions to answer?
> 10. Without any personal feelings towards X, will people add it to their "ignored" or "favorite" tags?
> 11. Can the questions to which X can be applied have other tags reasonably applied as well?
> 12. Is X **not** a tag that can really only be applied once there are answers to its questions?

For each point that you **fully agree** with, give the tag a score of $\color{green}{+2}$. For each point that you **partially** agree with, give the tag a score of $\color{orange}{+1}$. And for each point that you **don't agree** with, give the tag a score of $\color{red}{-1}$. Find the $\text{total score}$. If

- $\color{green}{\text{total score}>18}$, then it's an exceptionally good tag. Go ahead and create it, if it doesn't exist already!
- $\color{orange}{18>\text{total score}>14}$, then it's a good tag. Make a judgement call and decide whether or not to create it.
- $\color{red}{\text{total score}<14}$, then it's not a good tag. Make sure to ask on meta before creating it, or it already exists make a meta post to ask for its possible [burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag). Read: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/437611).

<sub>1: Ignore spam and be aware that [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) are dead.</sub>
<sub>2: A tag should be a tag, not more, not less. Ideally, a tag should be present only be on less than $\frac{1}{10}$th of an SE site's questions.</sub>

---

**Important Note:** Please write up the [tag excerpt](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) when you create a new tag. It's okay to copy over the corresponding definition from Wikipedia or some published paper, but in that case make sure you mention the source in brackets - something like `(Wikipedia)` or `(arXiv:xxxx.yyyy)` would suffice. It's always *preferable* that you write the definitions in your own words but I do realize that that can sometimes be time-consuming.  However, do keep in mind that tag excerpts should ideally contain not only the definitions but also guidance on how and when to use them.

Comment: A test that would be a little bit easier would be the "reverse-removal-test". Any tag that does not fail [the criteria in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) should not be removed and is therefore no exceptionally bad tag.